# NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/gdata/client/GoogleService

Tags: java

I've downloaded .jar file from: http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/g/Downloadgdataclient10jar.htm
and it lacks GoogleService class which is used by application I am trying to run.
My question is then: from where can I download gdata-client-1.0.jar with GoogleService class ?

Comment: [Here](https://developers.google.com/gdata/docs/client-libraries) you will find library with docs.

Comment: @Syed Muhammed Umair - I will give it a shot